# How to make WINE be quiet about MSVCR errors?

Tags: wine, python

I downloaded the Python 2.7 MSI installer for Windows and proceeded to install it with Wine. It worked without any problems.

However, running `wine python.exe` leads to a whole bunch of these errors:

> fixme:msvcrt:MSVCRT__sopen : pmode 0x81b6 ignored

The application technically works, but is very hard to use because of these error messages. (They come up multiple times while the program is running.)

Is there a way to tell Wine to ignore these messages?

Comment: I can't be the only one wondering why you'd want to run Python through Wine...

Comment: @flute: Because the app needs to be cross-platform and I don't want to boot Windows just to test it.

Comment: I've been there. And have changed to VirtualBox. Testing is way more reliable.

Comment: @Javier: But I actually got it working :P

Comment: I should note that I ended up with Python 2.6 and not 2.7 - not a big problem, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a lot of control on the wine error output, to turn off all the fixme, just run:

```
WINEDEBUG=fixme-all wine python.exe program
```

You can read the wine [man page](http://www.winehq.org/docs/wine) to find all the possible options.